# Overriding paypal module template files in prestashop

Tags: templates, module, paypal, smarty, prestashop

I've been creating a theme for prestashop and found out pretty early on that you could override module templates by creating a folder in myTheme/modules/modulename and then put the overriding templates in there, however, when I try and do this for the paypal module the overriden template file does not get used.

Have any other prestashop users had this problem in the past and if so how have you fixed it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem because I was copying the files from modules I wanted to override into my theme directory and deleting those I wasn't overriding.

However, PayPal's module is several levels deep. You can't leave the files where they are, they need to be in the root of the override dir.

Para example, to override `express_checkout_payment.tpl`:

Copy `/app/modules/paypal/views/templates/hook/express_checkout_payment.tpl`
to `/app/themes/han/modules/paypal/express_checkout_payment.tpl`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and found a workaround on [prestashop forums](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/index.php?/topic/180186-how-to-override-tpl-files-of-the-paypal-module/page__view__findpost__p__1027830).

It implies to modify the paypal module code, it's not a perfect solution, but it works...

Comment: In the end I decided to directly edit the module's TPL file and hope that the module authors fix this in the future, I saved this file off the live version in case the client overrides it while updating.